# kibana how to get cumulative sum in Data table visualization

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a Data table Visualization in Kibana, which displays the sum of sales per product per day and I want to add or replace it with a cumulative sum of sales.

Maybe is pretty simple and I missed something... is there a way to do this in Kibana? 
This should be the relevant link to ELK guide:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/search-aggregations-pipeline-cumulative-sum-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-pipeline-cumulative-sum-aggregation